# Like Button on Mobile App with out redirecting you to FB page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

is there a way for mobile app developers to add FB functionality that allows you to “like” something without actually leaving the page/ app from which you are doing it in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The Like Button is currently Facebook's only Social Plugin that is available for Mobile web apps.

How to implement it is described in Facebook's [Mobile Web Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/).

Here is a [simple example app](http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hello/) with a Like Button.